# No funcionan mis archivos ".js" ni en el navegador o Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript

No puedo ejecutar ninguna clase de archivo de tipo js y los propios archivos aparecen en blanco, cuando intento revisarlos en mis documentos.

Este problema se muestra incluso en Visual Studio Code o el navegador, ya que en la extensión "live preview" aparece en blanco y el navegador solo muestra error o no abre el archivo.

No tengo este problema con ninguno de los otros archivos creados con vscode.

Si alguien también tuvo este problema y pudo resolverlo, puede darme una mano.

Comment: Si no pones el código no podemos ayudarte, adivinos no somos. El error puede existir por muchos motivos, ya sea un error de código, un error en los paths o cualquier cosa.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, pero gracias por el consejo. El problema tenía que ver con el antivirus de mi computadora. Este bloqueaba las funciones js de la misma.

Comment: Cuidado con ese tipo de cosas y con extensiones, etc. a veces afectan a rendimiento y funcionamiento de webs, etc. Por otro lado, lo dicho, para la próxima añade que has hecho (código), explica por qué has hecho eso y que esperas conseguir y de esa forma la gente podrá ayudarte, replicar y todo lo que necesiten y necesites para solucionar tu duda, pero si no es imposible para la gente solucionar tus problemas y además seguramente te cierren la pregunta. ¡Un saludo!